# Approximate any Borel subset $A \subseteq R^n$ with a compact $B \subseteq A$ such that $\mu(A) - \mu(B)$ is arbitrarily small.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, approximation

What kinds of distributions $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^n$ (seen as a measurable space, equipped with Borel $\sigma$-algebra) have the property that every Borel subset can be approximated arbitrarily well (in terms of meausure deficit) by one of its compact subsets ? That is, such that

> *For every $\epsilon>0$ and every Borel $A$ with $\mu(A)>0$, there exists a compact set $B \subseteq A$ such that $\mu(B) \le \mu(A)$ and $\mu(B) \ge \mu(A) - \epsilon$.*

My wild guess is that any $\mu$ which has density w.r.t Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$ should have this property, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: I'm not clear as to whether you are asking for necessary conditions, sufficient conditions, or both here.

Comment: Any Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or more generally, a second-countable LCH space) which is finite on compact sets is both inner and outer regular (inner regularity implies the property you listed). A proof can be found in Folland's Real Analysis book on page 216.

Comment: @Mason Thanks, this is the kind of thing I was looking for!

Comment: @Math1000 I'm looking for characterizations (i.e necessary and suffcicient conditions), but I'm also fine with a very general sufficient condition like the one given by user Mason.

Comment: $\sigma$-finite and borel should do it